# Django JSONField: Unexpected array element

Tags: json, django, postgresql

I am trying to save a record JSONField in Django which is declared like this:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
   myfield = JSONField()
```

with this code fragment:

```
MyClass.objects.create(myfield = {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

but it results in

```
DataError: malformed array literal: "{"a": 1, "b": 2}"
LINE 1: ... '{"a": 1, ...
             ^
DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
```

I am trying to following the example described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Can anyone point out what am I missing here please?

Comment: you try to insert JSON data to ARRAY column, yet those are different datatypes

Comment: @VaoTsun but where is array column there? I declared the field as `JSONField`

Comment: this field requires PostgreSQL ≥ 9.4 and Psycopg2 ≥ 2.5.4.

Comment: @itzmeontv I use PostgreSQL 9.6 and Psycopg2 2.6.1

Comment: Sometimes Django misbehaves in mysterious ways: Try 
myfield={'a': 1,'b':2} (eliminate the white spaces around '='). Also, have you migrated the database?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this error is returned if the type-casting to a particular data type is not done correctly. I am able to get rid of this error by explicitly casting it to **jsonb** as: `MyClass.objects.create(myfield = ({'a': 1, 'b': 2})::jsonb)`.

As @John pointed out, eliminate the whitespaces and try it out. That may help too.